Angular Apollo - Graphql codegen - Handle optional and nullable values or wrong approach?
I was experimenting with Angular Apollo and generating types from schema.
I'm using SpaceX open API graphql - https://spacex-production.up.railway.app.
So I have installed all required dependencies and created this codegen.yml file:
codegen.yml
overwrite: true
generates:
    ./src/app/generated/graphql.ts:
      schema:
        - https://spacex-production.up.railway.app/
      documents:
        - src/app/graphql/*.graphql
      plugins:
        - typescript
        - typescript-operations
        - typescript-apollo-angular
      config:
        addExplicitOverride: true

Then I have created ships.query.graphql:
fragment ShipInfo on Ship {
  id
  model
  name
  type
  status
}

query GetShips {
  ships {
    ...ShipInfo
  }
}

And from that I got this generated reponse type:
export type GetShipsQuery = { 
    __typename?: 'Query',
    ships?: Array<{
    __typename?: 'Ship',
    id?: string | null,
    model?: string | null,
    name?: string | null,
    type?: string | null,
    status?: string | null } | null> | null
};

Then I have created component store service where with this interface:
export interface ShipsState {
    ships: ShipInfoFragment[];
    loading: boolean;
    error: ApolloError | undefined;
}

Then I ended up with this function for fetching ships, because ships can be array or null, then inside array ship can be also null? That's really ugly if you ask me?
getShips() {
    return this.shipsService.getShips().pipe(
        tap(({ data, loading, error }) => {
            if (data?.ships?.length) {
              const ships = data.ships.filter((ship) => ship !== null);
              this.setState({
                ships,
                loading,
                error
              });
            } else {
              this.setState({
                ships: [],
                loading,
                error
              });
            }
          })
        );
}

If anyone got any more experience with generating queries and mutations with codegen please let me know if I'm doing something wrong here, or this is standard procedure.
Thanks!
